# URL Rewriting (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

Actually I have a Wordpress page with an URL like this

```
http://www.website.com/gallery/?person=Mike
```

And I would like to transform it to

```
http://www.website.com/gallery/Mike
```

I tried with this in my .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^gallery/?person=$ gallery/%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```

But it doesn't work